# Task assignment optimization: multi-tasks multi-agents with priorities

Tags: algorithm, optimization, task

I have a 2-dimensional space, like a warehouse, where I need to assign various tasks to various agents. Say I have some agents (a1, a2, a3...aN), each one associated with its own actual 2d spatial position, and some tasks (t1, t2, ...tM). Each task is given a priority p1, p2, ...pM between 0 (lowest priority) and 1(high priority).

Each task is defined as "go to point x1 (take object) and then go to point x2 (store object)".

What's the best algorithm for assigning the various tasks to my agents, given that I want to save fuel (i.e. minimize the distance covered by the agents) between subsequent tasks, by also accounting for the priorities?

I know there is the Hungarian method, but it seems to be designed for the case N=M and takes into account for the cost but not for the priority; I know I might define a cost function as distance/priority though,  but is there any other nice method for this task assignment problem?

Comment: This sound more like a [Multiple TSP](https://neos-guide.org/content/multiple-traveling-salesman-problem-mtsp). The bad news: it's NP-hard. "Sounds more like" means here: this is a pretty informal description and i don't get how priorities and fuel = path-lengths work together. If priorities are due-date like, it becomes a time-window TSP. This could be softened with target-dates, but this somewhat leaves all that academic work available. Then there is the case of: maximizing priorities with limited resources (agents, fuel, time). You get the idea.

Comment: Ye, actually the deadline is not a big issue, since the priority is somehow time-dependent (priority increases for older tasks).